# Macro function with several lines for the parameter?

Tags: c++, macros

In C++,
I need to defined a macro.
That macro would take as parameter a "block" of code.

**Can we safely use several lines of code as parameter of a macro function?**

I was asking myself if :

1. is the following code valid, defined as valid by the standard, as in "cross-platform"?
2. is there a better way to do the same (I can't use template function there because I need the context).

---

```
#define MY_MACRO( expr ) DOSOMETHING( (expr) ); DOANOTHERTHING( (expr) ); // etc...

int my_function() {
    int o = RandomNumber();
    MY_MACRO( 
        int k = AFunction();
        k++;
        AnotherFunction( k + o ); // here I need to keep the context of the call
    ); 
}
```

We can't use functors because we need to have access to the context of the call.
We can't use lambda (snif) because we use an old compiler that don't provide it (and we can't change it).

Comment: what is the use of this macro?

Comment: Did you try it ? What happened ? My guess is that each expression "parameter" that you pass will need to be enclosed in `()`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Paul, couldn't find how to get the display right.
@CharlesB : It generate code that insert the expressions parameters in several part of the generated code. The problem is more related to: can we safely use several lines of code as parameter of a macro function?

Comment: @Paul R: We are trying right now, but the question is more if it's defined by the standard (using several lines for a macro) and if it's cross-platforum.

Comment: @Klaim, perhaps it may help with answers if you explain what do you mean by *context*. Do you for example need all the state in the caller within `DOSOMETHING` and `DOANOTHERTHING`? If not, can you not encapsulate what you need within a functor which you can pass to these?

Comment: @Nim: As I added, we just can't use functors or lambda. See the updated code.
The DOSOMETHING and DOANOTHERTHING macro here are not revelant to the question because it's the fact that we reuse more than once the `expr` that is important. As far as I can use several lines of code, I'm fine with the macro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

16.3/9:

> Within the sequence of preprocessing
>   tokens making up an invocation of a
>   function-like macro, new-line is
>   considered a normal white-space
>   character.

So the multi-line macro invocation in general is fine. Of course if `DOSOMETHING` and `DOANOTHERTHING` don't introduce braces for scope, then your particular example will redefine `k`.

Edit:

> We can't use functors because we need
>   to have access to the context of the
>   call. We can't use lambda (snif) because we use an old compiler

The usual way is to capture whichever variables you need in the functor, just like a lambda does. The only thing a lambda can do that a functor can't is "capture everything" without having to type it out, but whoever writes the lambda can see what variables they use, so that's just convenience, they could type them all out if they had to. In your example:

```
struct MyFunctor {
    int o;
    MyFunctor(int o) : o(o) {}
    void operator()() const {  // probably not void in practice
        int k = AFunction();
        k++;
        AnotherFunction( k + o );
    }
};

template<typename F>
void DoThings(const F &f) {
    DOSOMETHING(f());
    DOANOTHERTHING(f());
}

int my_function() {
    int o = RandomNumber();
    DoBothThings(MyFunctor(o));
}
```

You can also capture variables by reference (usually using a pointer as the data member rather than a reference, so that the functor can be copy-assigned).

If by "context", you mean for example that the macro argument and/or the macro body might contain a `break` or `goto`, and hence needs to be inside the lexical scope of the caller then you can't use a functor or a lambda. For shame ;-)

Comment: The example might be misleading : the macros I need can be used in a lot of functions and the "context" would be the objects availabl in the function's scope. Replace "context" by "scope" to understans what I meant. So here, the functor isn't useful as I would have to move all my functions and even different parts of the same function in functors. In practice, that would be hell. That's why I wish we could use lambda. But we can't :(

Comment: @Klaim: hmm, if you have to access so many variables that it's hell to list them, then I would be looking to refactor anyway, maybe express the logical connections between those objects differently than just, "they're all in scope at this point". Simplest way, make them all members of some stupid "state" object and pass that. Then try to work out how to make the "state" less stupid and more meaningful. But I accept you may be in a hole that's too deep to climb out of, or at least too hard to climb out of *today*.

Comment: What I meant is that I would have to do this for around 40 functions, not that there are a lot of variables in the functions.

Answer (score 3):

the way to make it work (at least for gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)), is to **use braces { } enclosing your actuals** for the macro.

A useful example:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define MYDEBUG(X) (X)
#else
#define MYDEBUG(X)
#endif

MYDEBUG({
  if (shit_happens) {
     cerr << "help!" << endl;
     ....
  }
});
```

Comment: @xaxxon Sorry I didn't get your question. What comment? I didn't write anything here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use extra parentheses to make your expressions look like a single argument which won't get broken up by the preprocessor, i.e. do it more like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO( (expr) ) DOSOMETHING( (expr) ); DOANOTHERTHING( (expr) ); // etc...

int my_function() {
    MY_MACRO( 
        (int k = AFunction();
        k++;
        AnotherFunction( k );)
    ); 
}
```

although I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: I haven't tried it either, but I think comma is the only thing that will break up macro arguments. Strange as it looks, you can put semi-colons in there without doing anything special, it's still a single macro argument that happens to contain semi-colons.

Comment: @Steve: ah, OK - that makes sense - I have had to add extra parentheses for printf-like macros in the past, but of course these would have contained commas.

Comment: This answer don't work : the ; finish the whole expression. To make it work, you need to put all the expresssions between () too. (we checked on GCC4.4 )

Comment: Yes commas between expression that would be between ().

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you *should* use a functor! ;)

```
struct ninja
{
  void operator()() const
  {
    int k = AFunction();
    k++;
    AnotherFunction( k );    
  }
};

template <typename Functor>
void do_something(Functor const& f)
{
  f();
}

template <typename Functor>
void do_otherthing(Functor const& f)
{
  f();
}

int my_function()
{
  ninja foo;
  do_something(foo);
  do_otherthing(foo);
}
```

Comment: Or in C++0x, without a name: `[](){ int k = AFunction(); ++k, AnotherFunction( k );  }`

Comment: Yes we thought about that, but the problem is that we need to keep the context of the call. However lambda would have solve this but we currently can't use a compiler providing the lambda feature TT__TT
I'm updating the answer, thanks anyway that confirm what I was thinking.

Comment: Don't know much about this thing called C++0x... :(

Comment: @Klaim, what do you mean by *context*?

Comment: @Nim: Look at the example, the code need to have access to variables in the calling function. C++0x is the nickname of the new standard of C++ (C++2011) that define the lambda feature.

Comment: @Klaim, I *know* that! :) I was only kidding, I tend to stick to answers in the current standard until the standard is finalised and ready for prime time... Again, re my comment, can you not encapsulate what you need within the functor (even if it's just references)

Comment: Functor would require to add references the variables of the caller function. If that's not automatic (like with lambda), we just can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

A macro with multiple lines for parameter is fine also in case of multiple arguments, it even allows "commas" inside, but I strongly descourage using "commas" beause if it is not ambiguos to a machine it is certainly ambiguos to humans:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MACRO2FUN( X, Y) x; y;
void function(int a, int b, int c){
    std::cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    MACRO2FUN(
      function(3,4,5), 
      function(6,7,8)
      )
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is "comma" in quotes?  Do you not mean the normal definition of what a comma is?

Comment: Borg macros and cpp use comma ad argomenti separator, sometimes is not very clear what the compiler Will choose

Comment: Borg macros and cpp use comma ad argomenti separator, sometimes is not very clear what the compiler Will choose

Comment: What is " ad argomenti "?  also you posted your comment twice.

Comment: Sorry, posted it from mobile. "Both macros and cpp use comma as argument separator"

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that I see is that `expr` isn't an expression at all. It even contains a declaration. Obviously, you're going to have a problem with two variables `k` defined in `my_function`.

If you can use C++0x (e.g. VS2010, GCC4.6) then you can use lambda's to capture context. Not that you'd need to capture context for such a simple case, nor do you need templates, your macro just needs a `std::function<void(void)>`.

Comment: Too bad, we're stuck with GCC4.4 for the moment :(

Comment: @Klaim it's tacky to complain about answers because of constraints that weren't present in the question.  This comment should also be removed.