# How to read a file at compile time in C++?

Tags: c++, compilation, include, file-handling, preprocessor-directive

I have been trying to look for a way to store files as `const char*` at compile time.

I tried doing this:

```
#define STRINGIFY(...) #__VA_ARGS__ // va args deals with commas
#define INCLUDE(path) #include path // error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter

constexpr const char* source = STRINGIFY(INCLUDE("source.txt"));
```

but unfortunately you can't place include directives inside a macro expansion. Is there any way around this problem? Or any other way to get the contents of a file at compile time?

Comment: In particular, you appear to be looking for this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26161526/8372853).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the classic way to do this is to write an awk or perl script that reads the data file and generates a .H file

Comment: thanks,  the only thing is that if I want to change the file dynamically I would have to run the script again.

Comment: so you make it a build dependency

Comment: which would you recommend between perl and awk for this kind of situation?

Comment: hmm, perl probably

Comment: And I would suppose that python might not be suitable for this?

Comment: python works too, it is the 21st century after all. But everybody needs to have written at least one thing in perl